In my chat app, receiver does not get the message in real-time instead need page reload to get latest messages using React, Node and Socket io project
I am building a chat app in MERN stack with Socket IO where admin creates users and then chat with them, only admin can create users, admin can see all users and users can only see and chat with admin, now that's working totally fine but now the problem is when i try to send a message from either user to admin or admin to user, in both cases, when i sent the message it sent successfully and render on my sender screen but at the receiver end, receiver does not receive the latest message i just sent, receiver reload the page then he immediately get the message.
(Note: for example if i sent the message at 5:30 Pm and receiver didn't reload the page but when he does reload the page at 5:35 Pm (after 5 mins), the message appear with timestamp of 5:30 which means message was there somewhere but didn't rendered).
Message sent by sender:


After reload of receiver page:

Ist snapshot

2nd snapshot

3rd snapshot

Related Code:
client/src/Components/Chat.js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addMessage, setMessages } from "../redux/slices/chatSlice";
import axios from "axios";

const Chat = ({ socket }) => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const [showEmoji, setShowEmoji] = useState(false);

  const [isTyping, setIsTyping] = useState(false);

  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);

  const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);

  const fileInputRef = useRef(null);

  const chatContainerRef = useRef(null);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser);

  const selectedUser = useSelector((state) => state.chat.selectedUser);

  const messages = useSelector((state) => state.chat.messages);

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;

    let controller = new AbortController();

    const fetchMessages = async () => {
      if (!selectedUser?._id) return;

      try {
        controller.abort();
        controller = new AbortController();

        const response = await axios.get(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/api/messages/${selectedUser._id}`,
          { withCredentials: true }
        );

        if (isMounted && response.data.success) {
          const serializedMessages = response.data.messages.map((msg) => ({
            ...msg,
            timestamp: msg.timestamp
              ? new Date(msg.timestamp).getTime()
                ? new Date(msg.timestamp).toISOString()
                : new Date().toISOString()
              : new Date().toISOString(),
          }));

          dispatch(setMessages(serializedMessages));
        }
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.name === "AbortError") return;

        console.error("Error fetching messages:", error);

        if (isMounted) {
          toast.error("Failed to load messages");
        }
      }
    };

    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      fetchMessages();
    }, 100);

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
      controller.abort();
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      dispatch(setMessages([]));
    };
  }, [selectedUser?._id, dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!socket || !currentUser?._id) return;

    let isConnected = false;

    const connectSocket = () => {
      if (isConnected) return;

      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      socket.auth = {
        token: token && token.startsWith("Bearer ") ? token : `Bearer ${token}`,
      };
      socket.connect();
      socket.emit("user_connected", currentUser._id.toString());
      isConnected = true;
    };

    connectSocket();

    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("Socket connected");

      if (!isConnected) {
        socket.emit("user_connected", currentUser._id.toString());
        isConnected = true;
      }
    });

    socket.on("connect_error", (error) => {
      console.error("Socket connection error:", error);

      setTimeout(connectSocket, 5000);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
      console.log("Socket disconnected:", reason);

      if (reason === "io server disconnect") {
        setTimeout(connectSocket, 5000);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      isConnected = false;
      socket.off("connect");
      socket.off("connect_error");
      socket.off("disconnect");
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, [socket, currentUser]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!socket || !selectedUser?._id) return;

    const handleReceiveMessage = (data) => {
      const messageToAdd = {
        ...data,
        timestamp: new Date(data.timestamp || Date.now()).toISOString(),
      };
      dispatch(addMessage(messageToAdd));
      scrollToBottom();
    };

    socket.on("receive_message", handleReceiveMessage);

    return () => {
      socket.off("receive_message");
    };
  }, [socket, selectedUser, dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.on("user_typing", ({ username, isTyping }) => {
        setIsTyping(isTyping);
      });

      return () => {
        socket.off("user_typing");
      };
    }
  }, [socket, dispatch, selectedUser]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket && selectedUser && currentUser) {
      const roomId = [currentUser._id, selectedUser._id].sort().join("-");

      socket.emit("join_room", {
        userId: currentUser._id,
        partnerId: selectedUser._id,
      });

      return () => {
        socket.emit("leave_room", {
          userId: currentUser._id,
          partnerId: selectedUser._id,
        });
      };
    }
  }, [socket, selectedUser, currentUser]);

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottom();
  }, [messages]);

  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    if (chatContainerRef.current) {
      chatContainerRef.current.scrollTop = chatContainerRef.current.scrollHeight;
    }
  };

  const handleSendMessage = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!selectedUser || !socket || (!message.trim() && !selectedFile)) return;

    const messageData = {
      sender: currentUser._id,
      receiver: selectedUser._id,
      text: message.trim(),
      content: message.trim(),
      type: "text",
      timestamp: new Date(),
    };

    try {
      if (socket && !socket.connected) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        socket.auth = {
          token: token && token.startsWith("Bearer ") ? token : `Bearer ${token}`,
        };
        socket.connect();
      }

      setMessage("");
      setSelectedFile(null);
      setShowEmoji(false);
      if (fileInputRef.current) {
        fileInputRef.current.value = "";
      }

      const response = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/api/messages`,
        messageData,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
          },
        }
      );

      if (response.data.success) {
        const messagesResponse = await axios.get(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/api/messages/${selectedUser._id}`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
            },
          }
        );

        if (messagesResponse.data.success) {
          const serializedMessages = messagesResponse.data.messages.map((msg) => ({
            ...msg,
            timestamp: msg.timestamp
              ? new Date(msg.timestamp).getTime()
                ? new Date(msg.timestamp).toISOString()
                : new Date().toISOString()
              : new Date().toISOString(),
          }));

          dispatch(setMessages(serializedMessages));
          scrollToBottom();
        }

        socket.emit("send_message", response.data.message, (socketResponse) => {
          if (!socketResponse.success) {
            console.error("Socket send error:", socketResponse.error);
            toast.error("Failed to send message");
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending message:", error);
      toast.error("Failed to send message");
    }
  };


return (
{/* Messages */}
      <div
        ref={chatContainerRef}
        className="flex-1 overflow-y-auto p-4 space-y-4"
      >
        {messages.map((msg, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className={`flex ${msg.sender === currentUser._id ? "justify-end" : "justify-start"}`}
          >
            <div
              className={`max-w-[70%] p-2 rounded-lg ${msg.sender === currentUser._id
                  ? "bg-blue-500 text-white"
                  : "bg-gray-100"
                }`}
            >
              {msg.type === "image" ? (
                <img
                  src={msg.content || msg.imageUrl}
                  alt="Shared"
                  className="max-w-full rounded"
                />
              ) : msg.type === "file" ? (
                <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
                  <MdAttachFile />
                  <span>{msg.fileName}</span>
                </div>
              ) : (
                  <p>{msg.content || msg.text || ""}</p>
                )}

              <span className="text-xs opacity-70 mt-1 block">
                {format(new Date(msg.timestamp), "HH:mm")}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
      </div>
)

server/models/Message.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    sender: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    receiver: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true, 
    },
    content: {
      type: String,
      required: function () {
        return this.type === "text";
        }
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["text", "image", "file"],
      default: "text",
    },
    fileName: {
      type: String,
    },
    read: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

// Add a compound index to prevent duplicate messages
messageSchema.index(
  {
    sender: 1,
    receiver: 1,
    content: 1,
    timestamp: 1,
  },
  { unique: true }
);

// Index for faster queries
messageSchema.index({ sender: 1, receiver: 1 });
messageSchema.index({ createdAt: -1 });

// Check if model exists before creating it
module.exports =
  mongoose.models.Message || mongoose.model("Message", messageSchema);


client/src/redux/slices/chatSlice.js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  selectedUser: null,
  messages: [],
  conversations: [],
};

const chatSlice = createSlice({
  name: "chat",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setSelectedUser: (state, action) => {
      state.selectedUser = action.payload;
    },
    setMessages: (state, action) => {
      state.messages = action.payload;
    },
    addMessage: (state, action) => {
      state.messages.push(action.payload);
    },
    clearMessages: (state) => {
      state.messages = [];
    },
    setConversations: (state, action) => {
      state.conversations = action.payload;
    },
    addConversation: (state, action) => {
      if (
        !state.conversations.find((conv) => conv._id === action.payload._id)
      ) {
        state.conversations.push(action.payload);
      }
    },
    updateConversation: (state, action) => {
      const index = state.conversations.findIndex(
        (conv) => conv._id === action.payload._id
      );
      if (index !== -1) {
        state.conversations[index] = action.payload;
      }
    },
  },
});

export const {
  setSelectedUser,
  setMessages,
  addMessage,
  clearMessages,
  setConversations,
  addConversation,
  updateConversation,
} = chatSlice.actions;

export default chatSlice.reducer;



socket.on("receive_message", handleReceiveMessage); -> But where is any "receive_message" event emitted on the socket connection? The client is using socket.emit("send_message", ...) t send messages on the socket though. Should these either both be the same event, e.g. both "receive_message" or "send_message" events?

If you see the flow of fetching messages, receiving messages are fetched by database and if i fetch them socket and on page reload, it fetch all the messages from database, e.g. messages history , which duplicate the last message, i am stuck with this loop hole
